# jQuery Plugin - document is null - jQuery calls createSafeFrag()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin and i wanted to have multiple functions to be available like this:

```
//Calling the "constructor"
$(element).pluginName();

//Calling the "method"
$(element).pluginName.methodName();
```

So what i basically did was this:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    //The "constructor"
    $.fn.pluginName = function() {
        //try accessing $(this)
        var meh = $(this);
    };
    //The "method"
    $.fn.pluginName.methodName = function() {
        //try accessing $(this)
        var test = $(this);
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Now when i call it just as i described it in the box above, it works for the "constructor". But when i try the "method", i get an error:

```
TypeError: document is null
http://(url)/jquery.js
safeFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
Line 5823
```

Now to the funny part: When i rename the "method" to `$.fn.pluginNameMethodName` (so basically, if i remove the last `.`), i can call the "method" by calling `$(element).pluginNameMethodName();`.

So, what am i doing wrong?

I want my plugin to have multiple easily accessible methods (i don't want my plugins methods to be called with `$(element).pluginName(methodName);`).

Comment: Check your `this`. I don't think you can fix this, though.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: You can't easily get access to the element due to the fact that methodname is a property of $.fn.pluginName rather than $.fn. .methodName can't access the appropriate instance of $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want easily accessible methods, have your plugin provide an interface stored on the element.

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    //The "constructor"
    $.fn.pluginName = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var obj = {
                elem: this,
                theMethod: function(){
                    var meh = this.elem;
                }
            };
            $(this).data("pluginName",obj);
        })
    };
})(jQuery)

// using it
var pluginInterface = $(theelement).pluginName().data("pluginName");
pluginInterface.theMethod();
```

Though, i consider `$(element).pluginName(methodName);` to be easily accessible too. (moreso even).

Comment: So after some tries, i decided to go with the `$(element).pluginName(methodName);` notation. thanks tho!